# RAID 1 - mdadm or btrfs?

Tags: server, raid, mdadm, btrfs

I want to create a RAID 1 array of two (inexpensive) HDDs, in order to keep some rarely accessed data. I have thought about two main ways to create it:

- using mdadm
- using btrfs

I've read about benefits and potential drawbacks of each of them, and I am interested about opinions from people who have tried either (or both) alternatives.
My main interest is data reliability, especially when one of the HDDs will no longer work. Speed is not a big concern, as the data will be rarely accessed and mostly in an intra-LAN mode.

I will use Ubuntu 18.04 or (directly) Ubuntu 20.04, as it will be soon released. The hardware config is decent: Intel i7 + 16 GB RAM + 128 GB NVMe

Thank you, in advance

Comment: Asking about opinions is discouraged at this site.

Comment: @Pilot6 - understood. My main request is for recommendations/advice from people who have tried the same setup(s), as I want to know the problems that they had.

Comment: This doesn't fir Q&A format. Your question can't be answered.